# Get path of file at launch, use it in bat script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, vbscript

I have a need to change the file type association for an extension, for example ".txt", to open a bat script instead of notepad.exe.  The bat script will contain some checks I need to run, and depending on the results it will open the launched ".txt" file with either Notepad or Notepad++.

How can I get the path of the file that was launched into the bat script so it can be opened after I run my checks?  It could be many different files.

Note: I am only using Notepad and Notepad++ as an example.

If this can be done in VBScript or PowerShell that is great, but a bat script is preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the file path by accessing the batch file parameters.

For example, you would open your file in Notepad like this:

```
NOTEPAD "%1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use commands **assoc** and **ftype** for more information type `assoc /?` And `ftype /?`

Comment: I forgot a line in my initial question:  How can I get the path of the file that was launched into the bat script so it can be opened after I run my checks? It could be many different files.

Answer (score 0):

Open regedit and change         `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.ext\OpenWithList` settings..

Comment: I forgot a line in my initial question: How can I get the path of the file that was launched into the bat script so it can be opened after I run my checks? It could be many different files.